# Inconsistent accessibility: property type is less accessible

Tags: c#, properties

Please can someone help with the following error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'Test.Delivery' is less accessible than property 'Test.Form1.thelivery'

```
private Delivery thedelivery;

public Delivery thedelivery
{
    get { return thedelivery; }
    set { thedelivery = value; }
}
```

I'm not able to run the program due to the error message of inconsistency.

Here is my delivery class:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Delivery
    {
        private string name;
        private string address;
        private DateTime arrivalTime;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get { return address; }
            set { address = value; }
        }

        public DateTime ArrivlaTime
        {
            get { return arrivalTime; }
            set { arrivalTime = value; }
        }

        public string ToString()
        {
            { return name + address + arrivalTime.ToString(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 258, accepted):

make your class **`public`** access modifier,

**just add `public` keyword infront of your class name**

```
 namespace Test
{
  public  class Delivery
    {
        private string name;
        private string address;
        private DateTime arrivalTime;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get { return address; }
            set { address = value; }
        }

        public DateTime ArrivlaTime
        {
            get { return arrivalTime; }
            set { arrivalTime = value; }
        }

        public string ToString()
        {
            { return name + address + arrivalTime.ToString(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My solution was to **REMOVE** `public` from my class definition.

Answer (score 18):

Your class `Delivery` has no access modifier, which means it defaults to `internal`. If you then try to expose a property of that type as `public`, it won't work. Your type (class) needs to have the same, or higher access as your property.

More about access modifiers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Your `Delivery` class is internal (the default visibility for classes), however the property (and presumably the containing class) are public, so the property is more accessible than the `Delivery` class. You need to either make `Delivery` public, or restrict the visibility of the `thelivery` property.